# How can I get a weak reference to the send method of a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, weak-references

The [`weakref` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html) doesn't seem to provide a method for creating a weak reference to the `send` method of a generator:

```
import weakref

def gen(): yield

g=gen()
w_send=weakref.ref(g.send)
w_send() # <- this is None; the g.send object is ephemeral
```

I didn't think it would work but I did try the `weakref.WeakMethod` just in case as well:

```
>>> w_send=weakref.WeakMethod(g.send)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ricky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\weakref.py", line 50, in __new__
    .format(type(meth))) from None
TypeError: argument should be a bound method, not <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

How can this be done without wrapping the generator in a custom class? Like this:

```
import weakref

def gen(): yield

class MyGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        self._generator = gen()
    def send(self, arg):
        return self._generator.send(arg)

g = MyGenerator()
ref = weakref.WeakMethod(g.send)
```

I don't want to do this. Is there a better way?

---

The reason I want to do this is I am working on an idea for a simple messaging protocol for an app I might build. The messaging looks something like this:

```
# messaging module

from typing import Generator
from functools import wraps
from collections import NamedTuple
import weakref

class Message(NamedTuple):
    channel: int
    content: str

_REGISTRY = {}

def _do_register(channel, route):
    # handle bound methods
    if hasattr(route,"__self__") and hasattr(route,"__func__"):
        route_ref = weakref.WeakMethod(route)
    # handle generators
    elif isinstance(route, Generator):
        route_ref = weakref.ref(route.send) # get weak ref to route.send here
    # all other callables
    else:
        route_ref = weakref.ref(route)
    try:
        _REGISTRY[channel].add(route_ref)
    except KeyError:
        _REGISTRY[channel] = {route_ref}

def register(obj=None, *, channel, route=None):
    """Decorator for registering callable objects for messaging."""
    if obj is None:
        def wrapper(callable):
            @wraps(callable)
            def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
                nonlocal route
                obj_ = callable(*args, **kwargs)
                route_ = obj_ if route is None else route
                _do_register(channel, route_)
                return obj_
            return wrapped
        return wrapper
    else:
        if route is None:
            route = obj
        _do_register(channel, route)

def manager():
    msg_obj = None
    while True:
        msg_obj = yield _broadcast(msg_obj)

def _broadcast(msg_obj):
    count = 0
    if msg_obj:
        for route_ref in _REGISTRY[msg_obj.channel]:
            route = route_ref()
            if route is not None:
                count += 1
                route(msg_obj)
    return count
```

...used like this:

```
@register(channel=1)
def listening_gen(name):
    while True:
        msg = yield
        print(f"{name} received message {msg.content} on channel {msg.channel}")


a = listening_gen("a")
b = listening_gen("b")
next(a)
next(b)
register(a, channel=2)
register(b, channel=3)

msg1 = Message(channel=1, content="foo")
msg2 = Message(channel=2, content="bar")
msg3 = Message(channel=3, content="baz")

m = manager()
next(m)
m.send(msg1)
m.send(msg2)
m.send(msg3)
```

`a` hears messages on channels 1 and 2, `b` hears messages on channels 1 and 3.

Comment: Could you give some context - what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @jonrsharpe updated with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html):

> Not all objects can be weakly referenced; those objects which can
>   include class instances, **functions written in Python (but not in C)**,
>   instance methods, sets, frozensets, some file objects, generators,
>   type objects, sockets, arrays, deques, regular expression pattern
>   objects, and code objects.

Since generators are a builtin type written in C, you cannot create a weak reference to a generator's `send` method. The workaround, as you've already discovered, is to wrap the generator in a python class.